# Add upvoted not-so-recent questions to the main page

Tags: feature-request, questions

This new feature would provide an intermediate zone where the questions would dwell, between the strictly more Recent questions and the Hot tab.

At the Recent questions tab, after a little scrolling down, draw a horizontal line and below it, show only questions with a minimum of { 1 | 2  | 3 : to be decided } upvotes, otherwise respecting a scrict most recent order.

The idea behind it is to leave recent questions around for a while longer if they have received some upvotes. Nowadays recent questions fade away after 7 or 8 minutes, at least in the most active times of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an "Active" tab, it just does not take voting into account.

People have suggested previously including adding voting into the activity that is tracked on the Active tab, but a lot of people appear to be against that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about something closely related to Recent but just with a minimum upvote filtering.